# Проблема с bootstrap tooltip в связке с bootstrap tabs и bootstrap validator

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, валидация, tabs

Использую bootstrap tooltip + bootstrap validator, то есть вывожу текст валидатора в tooltip, если создать tooltip на первом табе, при этом находясь на втором, то tooltip съезжает. Почему так происходит?

**JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/dndj9sLx/**

Нажмите submit, и переключайте табы.

Answer (score 0):

```
.form-horizontal .form-group {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но тогда он съезжает вниз...

Comment: Может есть еще варианты?

Comment: Тультип от бустрапа глюченные, это я понял после очередного проекта, потому пользуюсь другим - https://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/